# Storing of Core Objects into the SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm having some sample **xml** data from the server. And i parsed xml and converted into Java Modal objects to be used according to my requirement.

But i stucked here!!!

I need to store the xml data into the **Sqlite**

So please can you suggest the structure that how store the xml content in the form of **Tables**.

**Xml Sample format**

```
<result>
<title>Some Title</title>
<b_data>
    <!First B Data>
    <b>
        <total>10</total>
        <c_data>
            <!First C Data>
            <c>
                <name>Name1</name>
                <value>15</value>
            </c>
            <!Second C Data>
            <c>
                <name>Name2</name>
                <value>15</value>
            </c>
        </c_data>
    </b>
    <!Second B Data>
    <b>
    <total>10</total>
    <c_data>
        <c>
            <name>Name1</name>
            <value>15</value>
        </c>
        <c>
            <name>Name2</name>
            <value>15</value>
        </c>
    </c_data>
</b>
</b_data>
</result>
```

**Java Classes**

```
public class A {
       public String title;
   public ArrayList<B> bObjects;
}

public class B {
   public String total;
   public ArrayList<C> cObjects;
}
public class C {
   public String name;
   public String value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have three tables A,B,C for each entity with field for each property.

For each one-to-many relationship you can have id field.

In your case it will be

B_Id in C table

A_Id in B table

They will indicate item's parent.

Comment: In A table you will have columns: AId as INTEGER; title as String.
In B table: BId as INTEGER, total as String; A_Id as INTEGER (this will point to parent node indicating that this item in ArrayList of an A object with specified ID).
The same with the C table: CId as Integer; name as String$ Value as String; B_Id as INTEGER (pointing to the parent B node)